Flip Fluids - Settings For Volume Force Field To Turn Fluid Back Into Object?
I'm still learning Flip Fluids, I've been reading through the docs and watching YouTube videos but the settings I try don't remedy what I'm looking to do. I have a vape object, and it liquifies up through the air on a curve, and I want it to come back around and be drawn back into the vape shape. I have a volume force field of the object set up but when I activate it, depending on the strength, it either turns the fluid into a tiny glob, a bunch of tiny globs, it just disappears, or it goes right through it or gets pushed away. I tried a demo scene to make sure it would work first, and it did, so I'm not sure if I have a setting wrong elsewhere in my setup that is causing this issue. My CFL is set to 1. I've been able to try several things as it only takes an hour to bake on my machine, but it's at the point where it's glitchy like this so I'm seeking help. Thank you.
Before Force Field Activates

After Force Field Activates

